# NgTinyUrlModule does not appear to be an NgModule class

Tags: angular

I am new to angular and I have been trying to use the ng-tiny-url but my program keeps on:

This likely means that the library (ng-tiny-url) which declares NgTinyUrlModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import {NgTinyUrlModule} from 'ng-tiny-url';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    NgTinyUrlModule
    
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

this is what i am getting:
ERROR
src/app/app.module.ts:16:5 - error NG6002: 'NgTinyUrlModule' does not appear to be an NgModule class.

16     NgTinyUrlModule
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

../../../node_modules/ng-tiny-url/lib/ng-tiny-url.module.d.ts:1:22
1 export declare class NgTinyUrlModule {
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
This likely means that the library (ng-tiny-url) which declares NgTinyUrlModule is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.